# Return rows if the eeid and date only have one value from paycode id

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, case

I'm trying to pull payid with time = 0 if there is no other payid's on the same date for eeid.

| date | eeid | payid | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/01/2022 | 123 | 669 | 0 |
| 10/01/2022 | 123 | 146 | 10 |
| 10/01/2022 | 456 | 669 | 0 |
| 10/02/2022 | 456 | 669 | 0 |
| 10/03/2022 | 456 | 669 | 0 |
| 10/03/2022 | 456 | 146 | 10 |

The return should look like this:

| date | eeid | payid | time0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/01/2022 | 456 | 669 | 0 |
| 10/02/2022 | 456 | 669 | 0 |

I've tried doing different group bys and counts and just get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists` to filter out rows for which another row exists with the same `(eeid, date)`  and a non-0 `time`.

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.time = 0 and not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.eeid = t.eeid and t1.date = t.date and t1.time > 0
)
```

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VVCmg6Gj)

Technically we don't even need to filter on `time` in the `where` clause, this is sufficient :

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.eeid = t.eeid and t1.date = t.date and t1.time > 0
)
```